Well-separated minimum on compact set
On the simplex $\Omega = (w_1,...,w_K : 0 \leq w_k, \sum_k w_k = 1)$ (I'm unsure why the curly brace isn't rendering), I have a continuous function $S: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I assume that there exists a $\omega' \in \Omega$ such that $S(\omega') < S(\omega)$ for all other $\omega$. I want to know if it's true that for for any $\delta > 0$
$$\inf_{\omega : ||\omega-\omega'||>\delta}S(\omega)> S(\omega')$$
I've tried several approaches but am not satisfied any of them work. Is this even possible, or are there additional assumptions that need to be made?

Consider $\inf_{\omega\in \Omega - B_{\delta'}} S(\omega)-S(\omega')$ for $0 < \delta' < \delta$. What do you know about this infimum since the function is continuous and the set over which the infimum is being taken is compact (closed subset of a compact space)? How does it compare to $\inf_{\omega\in \Omega - \overline{B_\delta}} S(\omega)-S(\omega')$?

@user176372, I was thinking in that direction earlier. The infimum should be contained on set $\Omega - B_{\delta'}$ if it is compact. But how do we know the set is compact? Is a subset of a compact set compact?

A closed subset of a compact set is compact. $\Omega-B_{\delta'}$ is closed because $B_{\delta'}$ is open.
